# Click event of Object of iframe does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I want to use click event of iframe which is load in wordpress page.
My code is as follow:

```
jQuery('#iframe_id').load(function(){
        var iframe = jQuery('#iframe_id').contents();
        iframe.find("#logout_btn").click(function(){
            alert("test");
        });
    });
```

If iframe is on server which uses http then its work but if iframe is on server which use https then is not work.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

I am loading codeigniter page inside iframe and on click of logout button I need to unset session set by wordpress.
My wordpress site and codeigniter page are on different server. and codeigniter is having https request.

Comment: Instead of using an iframe you can send a http request to the target server. Note that Same-origin policy applies to Ajax requests too so unless your target server accepts CORS you can't use Ajax here.

Comment: @Dips i.hv added an answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677310/click-event-of-object-of-iframe-does-not-work/37679613#37679613

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find("body").on('click'` . See the ***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/1326/)***

```
$('#iframe_id').load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find("body").on('click','#logout_btn',function(event) { 
      alert('test'); 
    });
});
$('iframe').attr("src","JavaScript:'<button id=logout_btn>Button</button>'");
```